# Does the compiler ignore internal functions that are never called?

Tags: solidity, solc, inheritance

On inheriting a contract that contains some `internal` functions that are never used in the child contract. eg.

```
contract Parent {
    function _someInternalFunction() internal{

    }
}

contract Child is Parent {
    
}
```

Does the compiler still include the internal functions in the byte-code of the child contract? Or is it simply omitted?

Comment: Do you mean inside ABI of child smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

A derived contract can access all non-private members including state variables and internal methods of the base contract.

In fact, the Solidity compiler copies the base contract bytecode into the derived contract bytecode.

Internal functions/ Variables can only be used internally or by derived contracts. So, the ABI will not show internal functions.

E.g Contract Base has an internal function (_someInternalFunction) and derived contract A inherited Base contract, even if it does not call it. If contract B inherits contract A it will be able to access the base contract internal function (_someInternalFunction) because A has access to all base contract internal functions and B is derived from A.

Something like this:

```
 pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Base {
    function _someInternalFunction() internal {

    }
}

contract A is Base{
    
}

contract B is A {
    function get__someInternalFunction() public {
        _someInternalFunction();
    }
}
```